# Windows 7 Notification Area buttons -- no borders

Tags: notification-area

I recently installed Powerplan7 Assistant for my mac

Anyway, I had to uninstall (doesn't support uninstall well) and now **the icons in the notification area in bottom right corner have no borders**. i.e., when I click on a button or the "show hidden icons" (the little up arrow) there is no border around the menus.

I don't have any normal pictures to show you (b/c mine doesn't work!), but if you have windows 7, just click on any of your notification buttons in the bottom right corner.

Attached it picture

[image]
[image: borderless_notification_area_menu]

Comment: Both pop-ups have a 1px thick #646464 border in your screenshots... Maybe you meant "shadows"? _(I don't have W7 myself.)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Start, type in *aero*, and choose *Find and fix problems with transparency and other visual effects* from the search results that appear.  Follow the steps in the troubleshooting wizard and it should automatically fix your problem.